# Difference between rinkeby.etherscan and etherscan alone

Tags: erc-20, testnets

Which is the difference between both?
Both are useful to have the own ethereum tokens or someone is better than other.
Can someone explain??

Answer (score 1):

Rinkeby is a testnet - a sandbox for safely testing and demonstrating where no real value is exchanged. Although it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it is not a real duck and the Ether is worthless.

Without `rinkeby.` is the real ethereum blockchain where everything is for keeps.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan is a web application that scans the ethereum blocks. You can see transactions that some address has performed, amount of ether or tokens it holds etc. Moreover, it is possible to see each transaction. Regular Etherscan does that for the. so called, mainnet. But using mainnet when testing your own Dapp is expensive. Therefore you have few test nets that are like the mainnet, but their ethereum is just for testing and is basically worthless. One of those test networks is Rinkeby. Etherescan that scans blocks on Rinkeby network is rinkeby.etherscan. It is pretty much alike the etherscan on the mainnet. There are howerver few differences. On Etherscan on the mainnet you can see all the "internal transactions". That is, when you send some ether to a smart contract's function that is marked with payable, you can see if and where that ether or its part is further forwarded. On the Rinkeby Etherscan it is still not possible. Therefore the later is a slimmer version of the main network's etherscan.